# How to change shipping rates of some particular products in Shopify?

Tags: shopify, e-commerce, liquid, cart

I want to change the shipping rates of **one product in Shopify**. If I change it from setting then it will be implemented on all products. I want to do it through coding.i'm doing it through the following approach but it's not working. Any developer here to help me in '**edit code**'?

```
{% for tag in product.tags %}
     {% if tag == "quartz" or tag == "apple" or tag == "Citizen" %}
             <div class="cart__shipping">{{ 'cart.general.shipping_at_checkout' | times:200 }}</div>
    {% endif %}
         {% unless product.tags == 'Default' %}
                 {{ 'cart.general.shipping_at_checkout' | t }}
         {% endunless %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think changing liquid variable will work for you.

STEP 1 :

You need to create new profile for custom shipping rates for product then you can add products and set the rate for this product.

[image]

STEP 2:

Add Products

STEP 3:

Create shipping zones

STEP 4:

Add Rate to this shipping zone.

[image]